# Worlight.Connect() throwing "Error retrieving device data"

Tags: xamarin, ibm-mobilefirst

In my Android project, I am trying to connect to the Worklight server (CLI) but after the client.Connect() method call, when I look at the task result, it has an error message saying **Error retrieving device data** and HTTP status 500. However, I can see the activity count increasing in the Analytics portal. 
I am following the sample that comes along with the Xamarin Worklight SDK. All I did was changing the Realm to another one and stripped out irrelevant methods and kept the **ConnectAsync & Connect** methods alone.

If I run the Worklight sample application that comes along with the SDK, I don't see this error in the task. It gets back a HTTP 200 and everything looks good.

```
Here is the code, for clarity sake.


    private async Task<WorklightResponse> Connect()
    {
        //lets send a message to the server
        client.Analytics.Log("Trying to connect to server", metadata);

        ChallengeHandler customCH = new CustomChallengeHandler(appRealm);
        client.RegisterChallengeHandler(customCH);
        WorklightResponse task = await client.Connect();
        //lets log to the local client (not server)
        client.Logger("Xamarin").Trace("connection");
        //write to the server the connection status
        client.Analytics.Log("Connect response : " + task.Success);
        return task;
    }
```

Comment: Does the changed realm exist in the authenticationconfig.xml on the server ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the Realm in **authenticationconfig.xml**. But no use. I still get the same error.

Comment: Another interesting behavior I observe is, even if I change the realm to some junk string in the sample **WorklightSample** application, it still works. So I assume there is something else that goes into that I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: Can you provide the security test from authenticationConfig.xml

Comment: **Here it is**

 <securityTests>
       
        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
         <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>      

 </securityTests>

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with you Android app permissions.  Edit your Android project options.  In the Android Application->Required Permissions list, select the appropriate permissions.  For example, one of my apps requires:

- AccessNetworkState
- AccessWiFiState
- GetAccounts
- Internet
- UseCredentials
- WakeLock
- WriteExternalStorage

I have received the same error message without the appropriate permissions.  Your list may vary depending on requirements.

Comment: more specifically android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SubscribeServlet is tied to a `rejectAll` login module which rejects all login requests. If you have not changed the login module, then this is probably why you're seeing your login rejected. 
Try changing the login module to a different one if you're using the `rejectAll` login module